# Pandas apply to large csv file

Tags: python, csv, pandas

I have a 3GB csv file that need to be modified.
I have a column that I want to apply lambda function to (that should change the value of the rows)

The solution i tried so far is to read the CSV as chunked file but the memory problem still happens

This is what i tried so far:

```
dataframe = read_csv(file_path, iterator=True, chunksize=10000)

for chunk in dataframe:
   chunk['column_name'].apply(change_row_lambda_function)

dataframe.to_csv(result_file_path, sep=',')
```

Comment: What exactly happens?

Comment: load only the columns relevant

Comment: Its just raises an memory error before the iteration finished (pandas.parser.TextReader._read_low_memory)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
# write header (column names)
read_csv(file_path, nrows=1).head(0).to_csv(result_file_path)

dataframe = read_csv(file_path, iterator=True, chunksize=10000)

for chunk in dataframe:
   chunk['column_name'] = chunk['column_name'].apply(change_row_lambda_function)
   chunk.to_csv(result_file_path, mode='a', header=None)
```

Comment: every time i save to CSV its overwrite the file, and some where in the middle of the file the program still raises the memory error

Comment: @JoeDoe: If you pass `mode='a'` to `to_csv` method (like MaxU has done), it will append the data.

Comment: I think that is working right now, but there is still an issue. after the last chunk have been appended that program raises the low_memory. this technique will also work on larger files?

Comment: @JoeDoe, it shouldn't happen, as we are reusing the same variable `chunk`. Check other things (beside this snippet of code). You may also want to check it using smaller chunksize